# Python: How to iterate over rows and calculate value based on previous row (part2)

Tags: python-3.x

[Python: How to iterate over rows and calculate value based on previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63421930/python-how-to-iterate-over-rows-and-calculate-value-based-on-previous-row)

Adding complexity to the same question, if there is multiple countries in the table, how to iterate for each country

[The table in previous question consist of one country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPQ8W.jpg)

The solution given in previous question is splendid. But, how to use the same code for table with more than one country. Multiindex and for loops?

Comment: groupby country

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.